# Not getting full ImageData in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2.2

I am having issue in camera code of phonegap,

```
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
      quality: 75,
      sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 });
```

in above code if I use targetWidth and targetHeight 500 or more I am not able to get ImageData full.

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
      var startImageData= "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      console.log('startImageData--->>>>>>'+startImageData);
 }
```

What should I do so I can get full "startImageData".
Basically what I observed is I am getting near about 4000 characters.What I need is whole imagedata which may contain more than 15000 characters.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in the success function should be something like below in ur code just try this `console.log(imageData);` inside success function its should give the imagedata as expected..

```
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

        var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
         console.log(imageURI);


    }
```

Comment: If I increase height and width from 100 to 500 then in imageURI I am getting only first 4050 characters.

Comment: @VInayak if u have height and width normal around 200 r u able to get the imagedata as expected....

Comment: no not even for 200. I am getting it for 100. But then size and quality of the Image is too low. And any how I am getting only first 4050 characters from Imagedata.

Comment: imagedata u receive is irrespective of the height and width attributes k i want u to pass imagedata to a panel with html:'<img id="largeImage">' as per the code i have posted and tell whether ur able to see the image u expected..

Comment: actually I am able to display image to panel but since I am not getting full characters in variable the Image is not full. Do you have any Idea, when I console log Imagedata I am getting only first 4050 characters.

Comment: k try with any other image r append the imagedata to panel without converting to base64 and let me know wats the result..